# Is it possible to set up a custom date range for a Low Entries tag that looks for events in the current school year?

Tags: date, low, events, custom

I'm having trouble figuring out how to do this - I have a Low Events template tag that I'd like to set up with a custom date range that searches for events within the current year, BUT that current year is based on a Jul-Aug span instead of a Jan-Dec span.  Any guidance or examples would be hugely appreciated!

Answer (score 0):

According to the Low Events documentation on [custom date ranges:](http://gotolow.com/addons/low-events/docs/tags#custom-date-range)

> There are two ways to define a custom date range: using just the `date`
>   parameter or using both the `date_from` and `date_to` parameters.

If you opt to use just the `date` parameter then you'll want to use a `;` to separate the start and end dates. For example:

```
{exp:low_events:entries
    channel="events"
    disable="categories|category_fields|member_data|pagination"
    date="2014-09-01;2015-06-12"
}
    <li>{title}</li>    
{/exp:low_events:entries}
```

Check the documentation for the [Entries tag](http://gotolow.com/addons/low-events/docs/tags#entries-tag) and if you are still having trouble after that, update your original question with some template code and I can try to be more specific.

Comment: Thanks Alex!   I had hoped there would be a slick way to automate the date range so that we wouldn't have to go in annually and change the dates...but the time involved to figure that out vs. the time it takes to just manually update the range is probably not worth it.  :)

Comment: Your best bet there would probably be to make a plugin that would return a "current school year" date range and then pass that to the `date` parameter. That would allow you to avoid hardcoding a date range.